# RedHat distro on RPI?

Tags: linux, software-installation

Looking around for a RedHat (and the like) distro to run on the RaspberryPi (512MB RAM version), I came across [RedSleeve](http://www.redsleeve.org/), which has done the job of porting RH to the RPI architecture. They also provide the install guide [here](http://wiki.redsleeve.org/index.php/Install_Rasperry_Pi).

Has anyone got some experience with this OS? Any packages you've tried to installed that weren't available?

I'm also a bit concerned that there hasn't been any newer post on their site since Feb 2012...

Answer (score 6):

You can use Fedora Remix (Pidora); you can get the SD card image off the [Raspberry Pi website's downloads page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/). There is also a wiki with some instructions [here](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_Fedora_Remix).

There is quite a lot of stuff on the relationship between Red Hat and Fedora:

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux
- http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/the-fedora-project-open-source-evolved

These links have a little about it:

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Project

Fedora is also updated more often (Red Hat only really uses stable packages), and includes [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) - it is also more community driven, and is free.

I have used Fedora often, and if anything it is easier to use than RHEL. The version of the Pi works very well - I'm using it (my second attempt) at building a Pi based robot (box on wheels).

---

**UPDATE**

*As of early August 2015*

The current Pidora version is based on Fedora 20, which is EOL. See [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33960/is-fedora-remix-being-supported-anymore-is-a-updated-pidora-release-available) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=51) for potential updates.

Answer (score 1):

RedSleeve Linux is alive and well - the wiki gets updated fairly regularly with new installation guides and improvements to the existing ones.

The EL6 packages applicable to ARM are all there.

EPEL packages (the ones in Fedora but not in EL) are available in a separate repository.

RedSleeve EL7 is being worked on and will be made available when ready.