# Is Fedora REMIX being supported anymore - is a updated Pidora release available?

Tags: image, update, pidora

As a Fedora desktop user, and having just battled through trying to get stuff vaguely up-to-date on Raspbian (wheezy base image), I though I could install Fedora REMIX (i.e. Pidora) to see if it would be easier to fix the issue there.

The problem is the image is no longer available on the [offical Pi downloads](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) page, and the [version that is available is 20](http://pidora.ca/pidora/releases/), which is a old version (almost as old as Debian Wheezy) that went EOL with the release of 22 (a month or so ago). So can it is possible to get a newer image as a download, or via (available) instructions to modify a Fedora ARM base image?

Also, would the normal [Fedora ARM version](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM) be suitable (is it missing the Pi GPIO drivers & libaries?).

Using a old Raspberry Pi B (2011) if it matters *(which I don't thing supports Ubuntu Snappy)*, it would be interesting to know it if is supported whether Fedora REMIX supports the new model. Otherwise I'll just update the Raspbian image installed to Jessie... or manually modify a Fedora ARM base to suit what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The Fedora ARM version will only run on the rpi2 (ARMv7).

No one has bothered to make an ARMv6 build of 21 or 22 yet.

Keep an eye on this;

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=51